# Can my employer ask me to sign a clawback part-way through training?

Tags: new-job, job-change, united-kingdom, contracts, training

I'm currently in my final year of a sponsored degree. Our company is facing mass redundancies, but I'm confident my job is safe. I never signed a contract agreeing to a clawback to pay back my university fees, but I'm worried that they'll ask me to while reviewing my eligibility for redundancy. Would they be within their legal right to do this? Could I outright refuse?

I'm UK based in an SME.

Comment: IANAL, but I doubt they can press for a clawback since you haven't signed an agreement with them and its not stated in your contract  - so I wouldnt loose to much sleep over it..

Comment: What is a clawback?

Comment: @Neo Clawback means the company can take back money already dispensed. In a training situation, the company pays for coursework, degree, graduate school, etc. as a benefit, but if you do not work for that company for say a year or three after you get the degree then you have to pay them back some of what they paid for your tuition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're [safe](https://www.acas.org.uk/final-pay-when-someone-leaves-a-job/deductions-for-training-courses):

> Employers can only deduct money for training courses if it was agreed in the contract or in writing beforehand.

So in the unlikely event that they ask you to do so - you can refuse and politely point them towards the info from ACAS in the above link.

Comment: That's great news, thanks for the quick response!